# SQL left join not giving me null entries

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm producing an rss feed for wordpress, and the requirement is it should be ordered by promotion date if a promotion date is set of the article, or use post_date otherwise i came
up with the following SQL.

```
SELECT $wpdb->posts.* from $wpdb->posts 
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) 
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id) 
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta as m2 on ($wpdb->posts.ID=m2.post_id and m2.meta_key='promotion_date') 
where now()>(CASE WHEN m2.meta_value IS NOT NULL 
    then cast(m2.meta_value as DATETIME) 
    ELSE $wpdb->posts.post_date END) 
and $wpdb->posts.post_status='publish' 
and $wpdb->posts.post_type='article' 
and $wpdb->terms.slug = $slug 
and $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'article_$taxonomy' 
order by CASE WHEN m2.meta_value IS NOT NULL 
      then cast(m2.meta_value as DATETIME) 
      ELSE $wpdb->posts.post_date 
END DESC limit 100;
```

The trouble is the left join doesn't seem to return entries where there is no promotion date. Left join normally select all the column from the first table with null entries for the second when there is no match. Why isn't it happening in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You had two "AND" criteria in your query for the "terms" for the $slug, and "term_taxonomy" in the WHERE clause thus turning your LEFT-JOIN to an INNER-JOIN.  I have moved those to the LEFT JOIN component.  You should be good otherwise (also, I just applied aliases for the tables vs the long-hand writing for readability)

```
SELECT 
      p.* 
   from 
      $wpdb->posts p
         LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships tr
            ON p.ID = tr.object_id
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt
               ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
              and tt.taxonomy = 'article_$taxonomy' 
               LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms t 
                  ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
                 and t.slug = $slug 
         LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta as m2 
            on p.ID = m2.post_id 
            and m2.meta_key = 'promotion_date'
   where 
          now() > ( CASE WHEN m2.meta_value IS NOT NULL 
                     then cast(m2.meta_value as DATETIME) 
                     ELSE p.post_date END )
      and p.post_status = 'publish' 
      and p.post_type = 'article' 
   order by 
      CASE WHEN m2.meta_value IS NOT NULL 
         then cast(m2.meta_value as DATETIME) 
         ELSE p.post_date END DESC 
   limit 100;
```

For query performance, I would suggest an index on your post table on (post_status, post_type, post_date )